# Is there a function that combines Countif and Counta in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there a function that combines Countif and Counta? what I am trying to do is look for all the cells in the places column that are Dallas and count all the cells in the name column that have the name Harry?

| -Place- | -Name- |
| --- | --- |
| Dallas | Harry |
| Dallas | Harry |
| Dallas | Tom |
| Dallas | Richard |
| Chicago | Harry |
| Chicago | Edward |
| New York | Leo |
| Alanta | Tom |

Is there a function that combines the two? Or is there a different way I could do this?

I have tried using count, COUNTIF, SUMPRODUCT, SPECIAL COUNT, and none are working

Answer (score 1):

You could use `=COUNTIFS()`

In your case particularly, you can use the below formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(<places_column_range>, "Dallas", <names_column_range>, "Harry")
```

This will combine the two and provide the answer `2` according to your data:
Dallas and Harry appears twice.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using SUMPRODUCT

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A:A="Dallas", B:B="Harry")
```